# Change local administrator password in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I am looking for a way to change the password of a local user account (local Administrator) on a Windows (XP in this case) machine. I have read the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Reset-Administrator-Pass.aspx) about one way to do this, but this just doesn't seem 'clean'.

I can see that this is [possible to do with WMI](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/oct04/hey1015.mspx), so that might be the answer, but I can't figure out how to use the WinNT WMI namespace with ManagementObject. When I try the following code it throws an "Invalid Parameter" exception.

```
public static void ResetPassword(string computerName, string username, string newPassword){ 
            ManagementObject managementObject = new ManagementObject("WinNT://" + computerName + "/" + username); // Throws Exception
            object[] newpasswordObj = {newPassword};
            managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetPassword", newpasswordObj);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? (I'm using .NET 3.5)

**Edit:** Thanks Ely for pointing me in the right direction. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
public static void ResetPassword(string computerName, string username, string newPassword) { 
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1}", computerName, username)); 
        directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", newPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `DirectoryEntry` class instead of `ManagementObject` class.

Answer (score 1):

As Ely noted, you can use the System.DirectoryServices code to accomplish this per [MSDN](http://msdn):

```
String myADSPath = "LDAP://onecity/CN=Users,
     DC=onecity,DC=corp,DC=fabrikam,DC=com";

// Create an Instance of DirectoryEntry.
DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myADSPath);
myDirectoryEntry.Username = UserName;
myDirectoryEntry.Password = SecurelyStoredPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this example is using LDAP to Active Directory, the question was about a Local account.