# Check if local account has a blank password using Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I'm trying to build a script that checks to see whether or not the password on the currently logged in user's local account has a password that isn't blank in Windows.  I need this to run as part of a background check for security compliance; it's going to report to a Nagios server.  I need this done in Python, but I'm open to PowerShell if Python won't do it.

So, the script will need to detect:

- The username of the currently logged in user.
- Whether or not the aforementioned user has a blank password.
- Return error code 0 if the password is NOT blank, error code 2 if it is.

I'm stuck on just whichever bit of code will allow me to check if the password of the current user is "".  I have a layout which, without too many embellishments, looks something like this:

```python
import os
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import Tk, Toplevel

MyGui.update_idletasks()
MyGui.attributes('-topmost', True)
MyGui.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 150))
MyGui.resizable(width=False, height=False)
MyGui.withdraw()

ThisUser = os.getlogin()
ThisPassword = ...  # line of code necessary to test for blank password; this is the part where I'm stuck

if ThisPassword = "":
    tkMessageBox.showerror("Error For User Here", parent=MyGui)
    print "No password set!"
    sys.exit(2)
else:
    print "Password exists."
    sys.exit(0)
```

I spotted [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556594/how-to-check-if-windows-user-has-a-password-set), where a WinAPI commend `LogonUser` is used, but I'm not savvy with C#.  Python is more within my comfort zone, I just can't figure out how to check whether or not a password set is blank.  I don't want to collect the password, itself.

Answer (score 1):

If a user's password is not blank, then attempting a logon with a blank password will fail with the error code `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE`. If it is blank, then the logon will either succeed or, if system policy forbids blank passwords, will fail with the error code `ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION`. For example:

```
import winerror
import win32security

def is_password_blank(username):
    try:
        token = win32security.LogonUser(username, None, '',
                    win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
    except win32security.error as e:
        if e.winerror == winerror.ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION:
            return True
        elif e.winerror == winerror.ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE:
            return False
        raise
    else:
        token.Close()
        return True
```