# System.UnauthorizedAccessException calling UserPrincipal.SetPassword

Tags: c#, active-directory

when I run this code

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                                                adHost,
                                                                adRoot,
                                                                ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
                                                                adUsername,
                                                                adPassword);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
user.SetPassword(password);
user.Save();
```

I get this exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: One or more input parameters are invalid
```

The code is running from a command line using "runas /user:
(domainadminuser is also a local admin)
The context is created using the same credentials (domainadminuser)
I've checked that all usernames, passwords etc are populated correctly
Is it something to do with the way I am creating the PrincipalContext?

I'm completely stuck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**[UPDATE]**
Here's the code I used to get it working. I think maybe the ValidateCredentials was the thing that kicked it into life (possibly)

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, parameters["adHost"] );
ctx.ValidateCredentials(parameters["adUsername"], parameters["adPassword"], ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
user.SetPassword(password);
user.Save();
```

Comment: try using `ContextOptions.ServerBind` since you are binding using a specific server name. Alternatively you can leave the host name as `null` and it should take the default DC. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks v much. Tried it, no success yet but I am trying a few variations based on what you suggested. My adHost is an IP address of the DC, not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the code that works fine for a password request management system we developed in-house, do try and let me know:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain, null, adAdminLogin, adAdminPassword );
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, adUserLogin );
user.SetPassword( adUserNewPassword );
```

Comment: Cheers. Hmm, using exactly the same code as you posted above, I get this: ***System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007203B): A local error has occurred.*** (there's not much info in the stacktrace, but I can tell it's trying to do a bind). One of the biggest problems I have with AD is getting meaningful error messages back. Don't suppose you know of a way to get more information out of the exceptions do you? Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: Thanks guys, I (finally!) got it working. To be honest I'm not quite sure why it wasn't working before, but it is now using this code (see my updated question). I didn't need SSL in the end although I will start using it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Active-Directory is concerned with the Standard LDAP protocol the simple bind without SSL not allow to change any password. Clearly here you are using classes that can communicate with your server using non standard protocol, but your SimpleBind context option can switch to standard LDAP. have a look to @CodeCanvas code.

Answer (score 0):

When the Context is created, make sure to set the `ContextOptions` to `ContextOptions.Negotiate` . If you have mentioned `ContextOptions.SimpleBind`, `SetPassword` may not work.

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext (ContextType.Domain, "Name", "DefaultOU(if required)", 
   ContextOptions.Negotiate, "Service Account(if required)", 
   "Service password");
```