# Facebook password change, using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, passwords

I have a little problem and I will be happy if someone tells me what to do.
I want people to change their Facebook password. This project is in VisualStudio, using C# in data base. How to make this possible? The new password should be affected by tge username and the password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change password to user account, by c# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253893/how-to-change-password-to-user-account-by-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at their API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs ?

Generally, any site that lets other programs interact with the password in any way should be avoided. The proliferation of federated identity (delegating authentication to a third party) is one major way to avoid security issues across many web sites by third parties better equipped to handle the challenges of authentication. It also helps users and improves security by making it easy to authenticate and not reuse the same password across multiple sites - a major security problem

At best, your application can authenticate with Facebook and authorize the user to access your site / application using their login API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/