# How to sync Windows password with current session after password reset?

Tags: passwords, windows

I am writing an application to do the following procedures automatically:

1. It resets (or change - I know the old password) Windows local Administrator password using `net user Administrator *`
2. After resetting Windows password, it encrypts a piece of data using `CryptProtectData`. The encrypted data will be used later.

The problem I am facing is if I decrypt the data right after that using `CryptUnprotectData`, it works properly. However, after restarting Windows, the encrypted data become unable to decrypt.

I have also tested some other scenarios as below

- If I reset Windows password, then log off, then login back and call `CryptProtectData`, the decryption works even after restart.
- If after resetting Windows password, I use Windows' own Control Panel item to change password one more time, then performing encryption, the decryption also works after restart.
- Windows 10 also works fine, only Windows server has this issue.

I also found out that if I use Windows Control Panel to change password, the SAM file is updated by `lsass.exe`(timestamp changed), but if I reset Windows password, it doesn't. The SAM file is updated only when I log off/restart the server.

I've also tried other ways to change Windows password programmatically:

- `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, account)` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25296496/7345777
- `oDE.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword });` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253910/7345777
- Using PowerShell like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

All failed. My guess is the resetting process makes Windows password out of sync with file system. The new password only is written to disk when I log off because SAM file is exclusive locked by system. Therefore, the credentials change, which makes the decryption failed after restart. However, I don't know why changing password in Control Panel doesn't have this effect.

How to achieve this result programmatically, or at least by command line/PowerShell?

Comment: Could be this bug:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/cannot-access-dpapi-data-after-an-administrator-resets-your-password-on-a-windows-server-2012-r2-based-domain-controller-3967321a-26ff-a39d-86af-00f452ae8917

Comment: @pcalkins: Thanks, but I always updated Windows with rollup update. To make sure, I tried installing the package mentioned in the link but it's showing "This update is not applicable to your computer". I guess it's already patched in the rollup update. Moreover, it happens with server 2019 also.

Comment: FYI: You say "the SAM file is exclusive locked by system" but that's true of _every_ in-use registry hive (and yes, SAM is a registry hive, mounted by default under `HKLM\SAM` and I think also under a subkey of `HKLM\Security`). Both those keys appear empty in `regedit` because even Administrator isn't allowed to view them by default, but you can overwrite the ACL. They are not well-formed registry values (they use the `type` as data), but they are registry hive files and the OS interacts with them using the registry APIs. The not-well-formedness means you shouldn't poke them yourself.