# Change user password on remote computer using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

Is there a way to change a users password on a remote computer using WMI?  I couldn't locate any resources on this.

I'd just like to add that we are not using active directory and I need to write my code in C#.

Comment: Is the remote computer connected via Active Directory? If so, see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/15/how-can-i-change-a-user-s-password.aspx). You should be able to translate the code into C# pretty easily...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234845/change-local-administrator-password-in-c-sharp) that talks about a local change, but the final code looks like it should work for remote machines also, and it's in C# already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, these are VB Script examples in this [Hey Scripting Guy column](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/15/how-can-i-change-a-user-s-password.aspx), but they should be translatable:

> How do I change the local Administrator password for all the computers in an OU?

```
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Finance, DC=fabrikam, DC=com")
objOU.Filter = Array("Computer")

For Each objItem in objOU
    strComputer = objItem.CN
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrator")
    objUser.SetPassword("i5A2sj*!")
Next
```

The first part is AD based, but is just being used to *find* all of the machines in the domain. The second part (that does the actual remote password reset) doesn't rely on AD at all.

---

So, it's basically bind to `WinNT://<ComputeName>/<UserName>`, then call `SetPassword()`.

---

And this other SO question on changing the [local admin account password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234845/change-local-administrator-password-in-c-sharp) is already in C#:

```
public static void ResetPassword(string computerName, string username, string newPassword) { 
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1}", computerName, username)); 
        directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", newPassword);
}
```

Comment: Hah, I *just* posted the exact same thing as a comment. This should work, though.

Comment: @CodyGray - whenever anyone mentions using WMI to do *X*, my first instinct is to go searching for "Hey Scripting Guy" content :-)

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks ! Unfortunatly its my own lack of knowlage thats holding me back here. Im not sure how to translate those scripts to c#, and the solution in c# uses DirectoryEntry object instead of say ManagementObject .... so i cant really move forward with this.

Comment: @Janivz - have you tried using the C# example as it is? It should work. (I admit, I can't give 100% guarantee on that at the moment, since I've only got one machine where I am)

Comment: checking now :P isnt DirectoryEntry for use with active directory ? ( going by some function defs on msdn)

Comment: @JanivZ - You might need to switch to the overload of the `DirectoryEntry` constructor that takes a username and password, if the account your currently running under isn't shadowed on the remote machine and/or isn't an administrator account on the remote machine.