# Changing local administrator password from random computer on active directory

Tags: c#, wmi

I applied these instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234845/change-local-administrator-password-in-c-sharp) to change local admin passwords in my active directory. It works fine but under only condition, if I run the wmi script on my domain controller.

How can I change all local administrator passwords from a random computer in my active directory? Is it possible to specify some credentials of my domain controller which authenticate the process.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried to add username and password constructor of DirectoryEntry class but now i'm getting "The specified local group does not exists." exception.

Comment: I don't believe what you want to do is possible.

Comment: When I logged in my computer with domain admin account, the script worked fine again. But i couldn't make that logging in with domain admin account through script.