# How to check in C# if user account is active

Tags: c#, ldap

How can I check from C# if a local user account (namely the local Administrator account) is active?

What I actually want is a C# replacement for the "Account Active" = "Yes" (or "No") output from the "net user Administrator" command.

I'm afraid this question looks like a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591681/using-c-how-do-you-check-if-a-computer-account-is-disabled-in-active-directory) one, but I don't know what to pass in for the parameter for the root DirectoryEntry object. Tried different things like "ldap://" + Environment.MachineName, "ldap://127.0.0.1", "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName, but none of them worked. I get an exception thrown by the searcher.FindAll() call in all three cases.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: With "ldap://" + Environment.MachineName I get a COMException with message "The server is not operational." and ErrorCode=-2147016646. Same with "ldap://127.0.0.1".

Comment: With "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName I get a NotSupportedException with message "The provider does not support searching and cannot search WinNT://<machinenname>."

Comment: Also tries "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",User", but this gives another COMException, message "Unknown error (0x80005000)", ErrorCode=-2147463168.

Comment: can you use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create the context for the principal object. 
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

        UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Administrator");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Administrator is enable: {0}", u.Enabled));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. But the FindByIdentity call sometimes takes several seconds before it returns a result. So though its nice code, it's not the best solution from a performance perspective.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but I think there is some overhead opening the connection or something like that, because when I did subsequent queries they were very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can query WMI's `Win32_UserAccount`

This is boilerplate what MS's *wmi code creator* spits out as a reference;

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT Disabled FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE name = 'alexk'");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_UserAccount instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Disabled: {0}", queryObj["Disabled"]);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I'd link the tool but as usual the msdn links are dead)

Comment: That did it! I had to add "domain='" + Environment.MachineName + "'" to the WMI query to restrict the results to the local user accounts, but then it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 var server = "YOURMACHINENAME";
 var username = "Guest"; 
 var de = new DirectoryEntry {Path = "WinNT://" + server + ",computer"};
 var result = de.Children
     .Cast<DirectoryEntry>()
     .First<DirectoryEntry>(d => d.SchemaClassName == "User" && d.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() == username);

 var flags = (int)result.Properties["UserFlags"].Value;
 var disabled = (flags & 2) == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234845/change-local-administrator-password-in-c-sharp) isn't quite the same but they use `DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1}", computerName, username));`  Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's a local user, you need to call the win32 api funcion [NetGetUserInfo](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetUserGetInfo) to get what you need.

The example in pinvoke.net is almost what you need, however you need to change the level parameter to 2 to get the [neccesary info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. This might also work. Haven't tried it yet. I guess you're referring to the USER_INFO_2.usri2_flags field (UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE). Though I'd better avoid P/Invoke and stick with a pure C# WMI or LDAP solution.